# Dialog windows in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, dialog

I'd like to ask a general question about MVC and dialog windows. Although I'm not very experienced in MVC pattern I can say understand its principles. What I don't know is how to manage dialog windows using MVC. Let's have a look at the particular situation: I have a main View (Window) and the controller. In the main View a user now clicks on button or menu "Options." The Options window should be raised, of course, and display several choices for the user. But who's actually responsible for creating and showing the Options window? View sends the information to the controller that user clicked on "Options" button. But now what? Controller should create new Window by itself? I don't think so, it usually doesn't create any objects of type View. The View? I also don't think so, it cannot manage Options information from the Options window. Someone else, probably, but who... Can somebody explain me how this should work, please? My preferred programming language is C# but this is more about principles. Thank you.